# SQL query returns incorrect value in multi user environment

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

We have for some time now been seeing strange data integrity issues at one of our client's sites. After much investigating we have now isolated this to a DB call.

If two users call the same stored procedure at the same time, occasionally, one user will get the other user's result.

We have setup a test to verify this, and we have a loop N times calling a query.

If two users call the same query, we can verify that around 3% of the time, the wrong result will be returned.

The below is a sample of how we call a database query.

```
    public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string storedProcedureName, int timeout, bool cleanParams, params SqlParameter[] arrParam) {
        string connstr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ToString();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstr)) {                
            cnn.Open();

            // Define the command 
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {                        
                cmd.Connection = cnn;

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = timeout;

                // Handle the parameters 
                if (arrParam != null) {
                    foreach (SqlParameter param in arrParam) {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                    }
                }

                // Execute the command and fill the DataTable with the result
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }                                                 
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

If I comment out the **SQL Command** region, and just generate a datarow manually, the result is correct.

We are using **ReadCommitted** isolation level for TransactionScopes.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

**EDIT**: We've isolated the stored procedure and have now established the cause is a call to **OPTION (RECOMPILE)**

Clearly this is not safe in a multi user environment, without some sort of lock

**EDIT**: Below is the Stored Procedure which displays the issue. If I comment out the OPTION RECOMPILE, this works absolutely fine. As soon as I re-introduce it, we get the issue described above.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ViewSalesOrderHeadersTest] ( 
        @RowStart int,
        @RowCount int,  
        @SortCol nvarchar(20),
        @SortDir nvarchar(10),
        @SLOrderNo int
    )
    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        WITH QueryResult AS (

            SELECT 

            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY                                                    
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='SLOrderNo' AND @SortDir='ASC' THEN ORD.SLOrderNo END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='SLOrderNo' AND @SortDir='DESC' THEN ORD.SLOrderNo END DESC,                 
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='OrderDate' AND @SortDir='ASC' THEN ORD.OrderDate END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='OrderDate' AND @SortDir='DESC' THEN ORD.OrderDate END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='CustomerName' AND @SortDir='ASC' THEN ORD.CustomerName END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='CustomerName' AND @SortDir='DESC' THEN ORD.CustomerName END DESC,       
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='DeliveryDate' AND @SortDir='ASC' THEN ORD.DeliveryDate END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortCol='DeliveryDate' AND @SortDir='DESC' THEN ORD.DeliveryDate END DESC        
             ) AS ROW_ID,

            ORD.SLOrderNo

            FROM SalesOrderHeaders ORD          

            WHERE
            (@SLOrderNo = 0 OR @SLOrderNo = ORD.SLOrderNo)      
        )   
        SELECT (SELECT MAX(ROW_ID) FROM QueryResult) AS TOTAL_ROWS, SalesOrderHeaders.*

        FROM QueryResult
        INNER JOIN SalesOrderHeaders ON QueryResult.SLOrderNo=SalesOrderHeaders.SLOrderNo   

        WHERE ROW_ID BETWEEN @RowStart AND @RowStart + @RowCount -1
        ORDER BY ROW_ID     
        --OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Everything looks correct *in the code you're showing*. All of the objects are either `new`ed up into local variables or are passed in arguments. You need to find somewhere where **sharing** is happening - it's either going to be higher up (e.g. some of the `SqlParameter` objects are coming from static/global variables) or lower down (e.g. whatever SQL code you're calling is using a permanent table as some kind of "this should be a temp table but isn't but I'm using it as a scratch space").

Comment: This part of your code is *not* causing the problem. It's either inside the stored procedure or where the parameter values are set.

Comment: `OPTION RECOMPILE`, in and of itself, is not causing the issue. I'm not sure what help you're looking for here, since that's just another symptom and you're not isolating/showing us the correct piece of code for us to help with diagnosing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever please find the relevant SQL stored procedure. The OPTION RECOMPILE is causing this issue for us. If it is not the issue, then what is?

Comment: This may in fact be a bug in SQL Server https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968693

Comment: There have been bugs related to `recompile`, the one you mentioned has been fixed in 2009. I hope nobody runs their databases without patching them within 7 years...

Comment: To be sure what you actually have patched, run `select @@version` and compare it to http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com